# array is not accessible in Processing.js mousePressed() function

Tags: processing, processing.js

I am using Processing 3.0b5 to develop an animation intended for the web.  As part of this animation, I create a custom class then make an array of objects of that class.  These objects happen to be rectangles.

One of the rectangles is designated as a button that restarts the animation.  In the Processing environment it works well.  However, when I run the animation on a webpage using either the .pde file OR by including the code in the webpage itself, everything works about the animation except the button and I can not figure out why.

The button feature is implemented by using the mousePressed() function.  The error I get is that the array which holds the rectangles does not exist.  However, the array is a global variable, and is even used in other functions in the program.  It seems as though it just is not accessible in the mousePressed() function for some reason.  If anyone can give me some guidance I would be very grateful.

The entire Processing source code is below.  To see the button function NOT working online, you can go to www.koeziris.com

```
//Global Vars
float canvasWidth = 700; //don't use this line in website version
float canvasHeight = 500; //don't use on website version
int numElem = 250;
int numBins = 18;
int j = 0;  //draw loop counter
int yTravTime = 200;  // the number of iterations until elements reach their final y position
float[] binElem = new float[numBins+1];
Element[] elem = new Element[numElem];

//for buttons and color
int reButton = 100;

//for histogram collapse and expand
boolean clicked = false;
boolean fin = false; //has the histogram reached its final position once?
int clickcounter = 0;

void setup() {
size(700, 500);
for (int i = 0; i < numElem; i++) {
int bin = 10 + round(constrain(randomGaussian() * 3, -9, 9)); //determines bin of each element
binElem[bin-1]++;
elem[i] = new Element(color(255, 10), round(bin * canvasWidth / numBins) - canvasWidth / (2 * numBins), -1000*i/numElem, bin, 0, binElem[bin-1]); //creates each element
}
}

void draw() {
background(0);
for (int i = 0; i < numElem; i++) {
  elem[i].move();
  elem[i].display(i);
  j += 1;
}
}

void mousePressed() {
clicked = !clicked;
//println("clicked= " + str(clicked));
clickcounter += 1;
//println(str(clickcounter));

float reButtonXl = elem[reButton].xpos - elem[reButton].elemW/2;
float reButtonXr = elem[reButton].xpos + elem[reButton].elemW/2;
float reButtonYt = elem[reButton].yposFinal; //this works, but I don't really know why.  Since drawing rectangles in "center" mode, I would think I need to subtract off 1/2 of the height
float reButtonYb = elem[reButton].yposFinal + (elem[reButton].elemH)*2; //this works, but shouldn't.  Should need to add 1/2 the height
if (clicked) {
println("\n");
println(str(clicked));
println("mouseX =" + str(mouseX));
println("mouseY =" + str(mouseY));
println("reButtonYb =" + str(elem[reButton].yposFinal + elem[reButton].elemH/2));
println("reButtonYt =" + str(elem[reButton].yposFinal - elem[reButton].elemH/2));
println("elemH = " + str(elem[reButton].elemH));
println("yposFinal = " + str(elem[reButton].yposFinal));

}
if (mouseX >= reButtonXl && mouseX <= reButtonXr && mouseY <= reButtonYb && mouseY >= reButtonYt) {
  println("target clicked");
  background(0);
  j = 0;  //draw loop counter
  binElem = new float[numBins+1];
  Element[] elem = new Element[numElem];

  //for histogram collapse and expand
  clicked = false;
  fin = false; //has the histogram reached its final position once?
  clickcounter = 0;
  setup();
}
}

class Element {
float elemW = canvasWidth / numBins - numBins * 0.1;
float elemH = 5.0;
color c;
float xpos;
float ypos;
float yposFinal;
int eBin;
float xspeed;
float yspeed;
float binElem;
float spacing = 0.4*elemH;
//The Constructor
Element(color c_, float xposInit_, float yposInit_, int eBin_, float xspeed_, float binElem_) {
  c = c_;
  xpos = xposInit_;
  ypos = yposInit_;
  eBin = eBin_;
  binElem = binElem_;
  yposFinal = canvasHeight - binElem * (elemH+spacing) + elemH/2;
  xspeed = xspeed_;
  yspeed = (canvasHeight-yposInit_+canvasHeight-yposFinal)/yTravTime;
}

void display(int i) {
  stroke(100);
  // Logic for blinking element.  Only blinks when histogram has not been collapsed by clicking
  // and if all elements are in their final position and the time or iteration constraint is met.
  // would be best if iteration rather than time constraint since that is how movement is controlled.
  if (ypos==yposFinal && millis() > 6000 && i == reButton){
    fill(#6086ED, 200 + (55*sin(millis()/600.0)));
  } else {
    fill(c);
  }
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(xpos, ypos, elemW, elemH);
  //println(j);
}

void move() {

  xpos += xspeed;
  // Execute once clicked to collapse histogram. Fin is boolean indicator that the histogram was completed at least once
  if (clicked && fin){ 
    yspeed = 0.1*(canvasHeight-elemH-ypos);
    if (canvasHeight - elemH - ypos > 1) {
      ypos += yspeed;
      //println("1st IF, 1st sub condition");
    } else {
      ypos = canvasHeight - elemH;
      //println("1st IF, 2nd sub condition");
    }
    //Logic for re-expanding the collapsed histogram
  } else if(clickcounter > 0 && abs(ypos - yposFinal) > 1.0) {
    yspeed = -0.1 * (ypos - yposFinal);
    ypos += yspeed;
    //Logic for stationary re-expanded histogram
  } else if(clickcounter > 0 && abs(ypos - yposFinal) < 1.0) {
    yspeed = 0;
    ypos = yposFinal;
    // create the bounce effect
  } else if(ypos > canvasHeight - elemH / 2) { 
    yspeed = -yspeed;
    ypos += yspeed;
    //println("3rd IF");
    // keep elements moving upwards after the bounce
  } else if (ypos > yposFinal && yspeed < 0) {
    ypos += yspeed;
    //println("4th IF");
    // move elements into final hisotgram position
  } else if (ypos < yposFinal && yspeed < 0) {
    ypos = yposFinal;
    yspeed = 0;
    fin = true;
    //println("5th IF");
  } else {
    ypos += yspeed;
    //println("6th IF");
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you're naming two variables the same thing. This is fine in Java (running Processing on desktop), but can lead to strange behaviors in JavaScript.

I notice that you're creating another array named `elem` on line 61 which you never use. I'd remove that, and then look for any other variables that might be named the same thing.

Comment: Thank you!  Line 61 was indeed the problem.  I deleted it and it works perfectly.